# Does repeating the same function in a formula increase calculation time?

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-formula

I'll give you an example:

```
=IF(SUMIF(A1:A500,TRUE,B1:B500)=250,"EXACT",SUMIF(A1:A500,TRUE,B1:B500))
```

Part `SUMIF(A1:A500,TRUE,B1:B500)` repeats twice in this formula.

What I wanted to understand is:

1. Does Excel calculate SUMIF twice in this case?
2. Does Excel calculate 2nd `SUMIF` occurence when `IF` evaluates to `TRUE`?
3. If the next cell contains the *exact* same formula, does excel recalculate it anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking them in order:

1. Only if the first part evaluates to False.
2. No, see 1.
3. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

First part:

> SUMIF will be calculated twice if it doesn't equal 250. If it equals 250 then it will calculate only once.

Second part:

> Formula calculation will be repeated per cell even if both cells have identical formula.